# I am trying to get a list of all users who haven't logged in 30 days but code isn't working

Tags: grep, who

```
echo here is a list of the users who have not logged in for a month
olduser="who | grep | -u, -q +30"
if $olduser
then
 echo these users havent been logged in for thirty 30 days
else
 echo user is active
;;
```

Comment: Firstly, you are using command which is designed to list _logged_ users. I find it not useful in this scenario. More, is your command line lost during writing a question? It is not a valid not mentioning of providing some useful data. Please, edit your question, use code formatting and try to be more specific about what you tried already.

Comment: Use accounting, not `who`.

Answer (score 1):

One recommendation... edit the question with the following, to allow a more thorough/relevant answer:

- Your OS (i.e. Solaris is very different than RHEL in acct mgmt)
- Type of script/code (Bash, csh, ksh, etc) as it looks like this is just part of a script and not the whole thing, since we can't see the shebang (#!/bin/bash, etc..).

First thing I do notice is that your variable *$olduser* is not set to command substitution but to the literal string *"who | grep | -u, -q +30"*

Command substitution is generally done with `$(command_to_be_run)` or with backticks like `` `command_to_be_run` ``. And I don't think you are looking for `who` but rather should be looking, as mentioned above, at accounting commands like `logins` or `last` or even log files.

Something like a for-loop to gen a list of users, and from there using that last and your variable substitution to generate a last logon date for each invidivual so you can perform an evaluation statement like a if-then-fi if they are older than 35 days.

e.g. On Solaris 10, with Bash

```
LAST_LOGON_DATE=$(last $user | awk 'NR==1{print $5,$6}' | custom_date_convert_cmd )

if [[ ${LAST_LOGON_DATE} -ge 35 ]]; then
    echo "${user} is expired. Last logon: ${LAST_LOGON_DATE} days ago"
    important_commands_here
fi
```

Obviously sed/perl would probably be a better solution as far as speed of processing over AWK, but if you are in a fix and just need something working, that's probably a good place to start.

Look up your system STIG from DISA, as usually they include commands to do exactly this... check users last logins, users w/o passwds, etc...
https://www.stigviewer.com/stigs